# Cauchy subsequence in a metric space.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, general-topology, metric-spaces

Let $(X, d)$ be a metric space, and let $(x_n)$ be a sequence in $X$. How do I see that if $(x_n)$ has a Cauchy subsequence, then, for any decreasing sequence of positive $\epsilon_k \to 0$, there is a subsequence $(x_{n_k})$ of $(x_n)$ such that$$d(x_{n_k}, x_{n_l}) \le \epsilon_k \text{ for all }k \le l?$$

Comment: There are many $k$s in your question. I'm not sure they are all the same. Can you please make the variables more clearer?

Comment: This is what I call a super Cauchy sequence, and yes every Cauchy sequence has a super Cauchy subsequence. My recommendation, is to try and find a super Cauchy subsquence of $(1/n)$ where the challenging epsilons are ($\epsilon_k)=(1/10^k)$. It will generalize easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's enough to show every Cauchy sequence has a subsequence of the type you describe (because a  subsequence of a subsequence is a subseqeunce of the original sequence). So, without loss of generality, assume $(x_n)$ is itself a Cauchy sequence. For each $k$, the Cauchy condition guarantees that there exists $n_k$ such that $i,j \geq n_k$ implies $d(x_i,x_j) < \epsilon_k$. Without loss of generality, $n_1 < n_2 < n_3 <\ldots$. This is because making one of the $n_k$ bigger does not destroy its property, so you can come up with lots of procedures to fix  the sequence to be increasing. For example:
\begin{align*} 
n_1' &= n_1 \\
n_2' &= \max\{n_2,n_1'\} + 1 \\
n_3' &= \max\{ n_3, n_2'\} +1 \\
n_4' &= \max\{n_4,n_3'\} + 1 \\
 & \vdots 
\end{align*}

Now $(x_{n_k})$ is a subsequence with the desired property. If $k \leq \ell$ then $n_k,n_\ell$ are both $\geq n_k$ so that $d(x_{n_k},x_{n_\ell}) \leq \epsilon_k$.